# Java swing how to edit double cell in JTable

Tags: java, swing, numbers, jtable, tablecelleditor

I have a Jtable with one of the columns presenting price which should be editable. But whenever I try to update the cell value I get the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

the model for my product is as follows:

```
public class Product{
private double price;
private String name;
private Icon pic;

public Product(String name, double price){
    this.name= name;
    this.price = price;
}

public void setPrice(double price){
    this.price = price;
}

//other getters and setters

}
```

In my custom class extending AbstractTableModel:

```
private ArrayList<Product> products;

//constructor and other methods
public void setValueAt(Object val, int row, int col) {
    if (col == 2){
        try{
            double price = Double.parseDouble((String)val);
             products.get(row).setPrice(price);          
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }
  }

  public Class<?> getColumnClass(int c) {

    return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
  }

  @Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowNo, int column) {
    Product item = products.get(rowNo);

    switch(column){
        case 0: return item.getPic(); 
        case 1: return item.getName();
        case 2: return item.getPrice();
        default: return null;
    }       
}
```

Should I change the price to string? Is there any other normal way to do this? If I remove getColumnClass override price change works, but then I cannot display product Pic so this is not a solution.

Comment: please share your `getValueAt` method.

Comment: for why reasons is there double price = Double.parseDouble((String)val);, btw DefaulttTableCellEditor can retuns Object, question in this form (based on decription and code in your question) isn't answerable, or with too wide answer, many times here similair questions...

Comment: @rdonuk I updated the code.
mKorbel isn't everything the user types in just a string value that I need to parse to double?

Comment: What about try to use Double instead primitive type double? And (String)val, try to change it to String.valueOf(val)

Comment: @mKorbel wow, removing this double price = Double.parseDouble((String)val) and setting it just like this: double price = (double)val worked like a charm. Please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it

Comment: @cAMPy you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem with this line (what i analysed by your Code added in Question). You just try to parse a `double` Object into a `String` which is not possible in `java` because there is no child-parent relationship between `String` and `Double`.

```
double price = Double.parseDouble((String)val); //trying to cast double as String.
```

> This line of code will raise `ClassCastException`. because of `val` is a `double` type of Object not a String.

you may try this should works fine.

```
double price = (double)val; //try this
```

Thank You.